# BigQuery Join Google Analytics Datasets for Looker Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker

We have several websites (same website but different topleveldomains) and store the GA360 data in BigQuery.
The GA360 data for each website is stored in the same BigQuery project but in a different dataset (date partitioned).

Example:

GA360 GBQ Project

- Website 1
- Website 2
- Website 3

We are now starting to use Looker and I want to be able to analyze the data. My goal is to be able to create dashboards containing the GA360 data for each individual website but also be able to create dashboards containing he data for all websites combined.

As far as my knowledge goes for both Looker and GBQ the joining can be done in both Looker and GBQ.
Since both GBQ and Looker are quite new to me I am wondering how and where these datasets should be combined in the most (cost)effective way.

So my question is:
What is the best way to combine multiple websites' datasets stored in GBQ to be able analyzed in Looker?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details? How do you intend joining the dataset tables? Will you have visualizations for all the tables in the same dashboard? How often will access it? Will you need aggregations, only normal data or both?

Comment: It's easy to `union` the data from all websites have them exist in a single view. Gave you seen Looker code block for GA360 data? 
A lot of the work may have been done for you already https://looker.com/platform/blocks/source/google-analytics-360

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join between tables in different datasets by explicitly specifying the fully qualified table names in queries while creating derived tables in Looker. The data processing will happen in BigQuery

Comment: You gave a good answer, but it would be helpful for the question if you are also serving a code snippet or example.